# Waiting for another async function to finish before running

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have two functions that I want to run one after the other finishes. I'm using webdriver.IO so I need to wait for one function to log into the page, and then I want another function to run.

Other questions here on SOF are telling me to use a promise, however I need to use a `promise`, however when I wrap my functions in a promise I get the error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`.

I have a login function

```
const Login = async () => {
    const browser = await remote({
        capabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        }
    })
    const userName = await browser.$('#username')
    const password = await browser.$('#password')
    await userName.setValue(process.env.NAMEUSERNAME)
    await password.setValue(process.env.PASSWORD)
    const loginButton = await browser.$('button[type="submit"]')
    await loginButton.click()
}
```

Once this completes and the page loads I want to run another function.
I have gotten this to work with a `setTimeout` however I don't want to just have a chain of `setTimeout` in my application

Comment: either do `await Login(); anotherFunction()` or `Login().then(() => { anotherFunction() })` if the caller is not async.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give you precise code without seeing where this is called from: but presuming it's inside some other function, you just have to mark that one `async` and use `await` inside it:

```
async theOuterFunction() {
    await Login();
    doTheOtherThing();
}
```

(If `doTheOtherThing` also returns a promise you could `await` that too - and would need to if you want to run other code inside `theOuterFunction` after that. But there's no need if it's the last statement inside the function.)